# requirejs, jquery-ui "menu" and visual studio 2015 .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, requirejs

I am having issues with the jquery-ui "menu" widget.  I want the default cascading menu behaviour seen at https://jqueryui.com/menu/#default

I am using `requirejs` in visual studio .net mvc and it looks like everything is being loaded -- I can see the "required" "js" files in the derived page header. *Something* is happening.  When the sample page loads the menu is in a box, per the example above, but the "bullets" for the `<li>` items are still shown and the `ui-caret` glyph that marks cascading menu items does not appear.  The caret IS in the generated `<span>` for the list item though.

My main javascript file looks like:

```
    requirejs.config({
        //By default load any module IDs from js/lib
        baseUrl: "Scripts",
        paths: {
            'jquery': "jquery-2.2.3.min",
            'jquery-ui': "jquery-ui-1.11.4.min",
            'datatables': "DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min"
        }
    });

    requirejs(["jquery", "datatables", "jquery-ui"], function($, dataTables) {

        $("#categories").menu();

    });
```

The index.shtml file looks mostly like:

```
    <div class="content">
        @{
            var count = 0;
            var depthList = new Stack<int>();

            WriteLiteral("<ul id=\"categories\">");

            foreach (var category in Model.OrderBy(m => m.LeftLink)) {
                if (depthList.Count == 0) {
                    depthList.Push(category.Depth);
                } else if (category.Depth > depthList.Peek()) {
                    depthList.Push(category.Depth);

                    WriteLiteral("<ul>");
                } else if (category.Depth < depthList.Peek()) {
                    while (category.Depth < depthList.Peek()) {
                        depthList.Pop();
                        WriteLiteral("</ul>");
                        WriteLiteral("</li>");
                    }
                }
                WriteLiteral("<li data-value=\"" + @category.Id + "\">" + @category.Name);

                count++;
            }

            if (count > 0) {
                WriteLiteral("</li>");
            }

            WriteLiteral("</ul>");

        }
    </div>
```

The resulting html for the menu looks like:

```
<div class="content">
    <ul id="categories" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" role="menu" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-1">
        <li data-value="2" aria-haspopup="true" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e"></span>A
            <ul class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front" role="menu" aria-expanded="false" style="display: none; position: relative; top: -22.875px; left: 148px;" aria-hidden="true">
                <li data-value="12" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">asd</li>
                <li data-value="13" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">xcv</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-value="11" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Horse</li>
        <li data-value="14" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-5" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Ants</li>
        <li data-value="15" aria-haspopup="true" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-6" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e"></span>Birds
            <ul class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front" role="menu" aria-expanded="false" style="display: none; position: relative; top: -22.875px; left: 148px;" aria-hidden="true">
                <li data-value="16" aria-haspopup="true" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-7" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e"></span>robin
                    <ul class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front" role="menu" aria-expanded="false" style="display: none; position: relative; top: -23px; left: 148px;" aria-hidden="true">
                        <li data-value="18" aria-haspopup="true" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-8" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e"></span>red breast
                            <ul class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front" role="menu" aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="false" style="display: none;">
                                <li data-value="20" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-9" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">male</li>
                                <li data-value="21" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-10" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">female</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li data-value="19" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-11" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">white crested</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li data-value="17" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-12" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">duck</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Again, the project builds. I can run the thing.  I can bring up Chrome's developer tools and *see* that the menu items have been decorated but the decorations are not happening or something.

I'll also mention that I am a visual studio .net mvc newbie. I have written plenty of other apps using jquery under Linux with much fewer problems.  I'm not sure where to turn for this environment. I's do a fiddle but I don't know of one that invokes .net

Comment: The behavior you are describing sounds like you failed to include the jQuery UI CSS file into the page.

Comment: hmm, my comment is too big.  see my non-answer answer below